# For a strong prime $p = kq+1$, $\langle g^k \rangle \le \mathbb{QR}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, cryptography

**Context**

In the context of DLP-based cryptography one has to choose a group whose order behaves well with respect to the chinese remainder theorem. Ideally want wants the order to be prime. This is why for instance, one may choose for a safe prime $p$ the groups $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ or $\mathbb{QR}_p$. This problem studies a different candidate for DLP-based cryptography.

**Problem**

We call strong prime to a prime $p$ of the form $p = kq+1$ with $q$ prime and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*} = \langle g \rangle$ and $\mathbb{QR}_p = \{x^2 \; mod \; p: x \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{*}\} $ is the set of quadratic residues modulo $p$.

How can I show that $\langle g^k \rangle \le \mathbb{QR}_p$?

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but I am suspicious of the claimed result (i.e. the claim that if $p = kq+1$ with $q$ prime and $\mathbb{Z}_p^* = \langle g \rangle$, then $\langle g^k \rangle$ is contained in the set of quadratic residues $\pmod{p}$).  What if we take $k = 3$ and $q =2$ to give $p = 7$?  Then $3$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$.  However, $3^k = 3^3$ is congruent to $6$, which is not a square $\pmod{7}$.

Comment: It *is* true that $\langle g^k \rangle \subset \mathbb{Q} \mathbb{R}_p$ if you add the additional hypothesis that $q$ is odd, because this forces $k$ to be even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $p$ odd.

Either $q$ is odd and then $k$ is even. Hence $g^k$ is trivially a quadratic residue.

Or $q=2$ and $p=2k+1.$

But since $g^{2k}=1,$ we must have $g^k=-1,$ otherwise $g^k=1,$ contradicting the primitivity of $g.$ Now $-1$ is a quadratic residue iff $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}.$ by Euler criterion

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion

Thus if $q=2$ the statement must assume that condition.

A counterexample is obtained for $p=7=2\times 3+1$ and $g=5.$

Comment: Please see how I edited just adding a few `$`. And what did you mean with your last part

Comment: I also do not understand the last sentence of this post.